# Nested flexbox UI with scrolling content rendered differently in Safari and in MS Edge

Tags: css, flexbox

See the frozen DOM state of the page in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jxhc9Wvqkc368knlaBWO?p=preview).

The code should represent a modal with four tabs, of which the third tab content is open. Should look something like the image below (rendered in latest Chrome): three divs side-by-side which contain overflowing content and the divs are scrollable. On the bottom there's a div containing *Plotting method* text and a button. The same view is visible in Firefox as well.
 [image: chrome rendered]

What I see in latest Safari:

[image: safari rendered]

After disabling the style
    height: 10px;
from `.heatmap-multiple-variable-container`

the rendered Safari content is:

[image]

notice how the third content div, which is scrolled way down, does not present all of its content (the *Select all* row) as it does in Chrome. Also the div containing *Plotting method* is not visible.

In Microsoft Edge, the div containing *Plotting method* is visible but the same scrolling problem as in Safari exists.

Any ideas on how to modify the Flexbox layout to display the menu in the same manner for all of the three browsers? I'm really stuck, so any pointers you can give me are appreciated.

Comment: In Edge, the container holding the scrolling columns (`.pl-container`) is overflowing its parent container. That's why the last items on the list aren't visible on scroll. Maybe you have some top / bottom margins somewhere, but I'm not sure. To see what I'm talking about, change `height: 100%` to `height: 92%` on `.pl-container`. I only tested in Edge. ([revised demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xyKF2ePPE3gsH1IyMzod?p=preview)) ...

Comment: But this messes up the height in Chrome. You should try to provide a much simpler example of the problem.

Comment: First of all, everywhere you call "display:flex" you need to add a "display:-webkit-flex" so it works in safari, the others attributes like "flex", "flex-direction" need a prefix too, like "-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto" and "-webkit-flex-direction: column"

Comment: There are others hacks too that you need to add so you don't find bugs
"display:flex; display:-webkit-box; display:-webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this was a hard one! Add this to your CSS and it should work. (tested in Safari)

```
body .multiple-variable-selection-columns-container {
    height: calc(100% - 66px);
}

body .modal-menu .tab-content {
    height: calc(100% - 57px);
}

body .modal-wide .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
    height: calc(100% - 110px);
}

ng-include {
    display: block;
}
```

You have added `height: 100%;` to elements who have neighbour elements with there own height. You have definitely to cleanup your markup, but the CSS above should work for the moment.

I have added the `body` to get a stronger selector to overwrite your code. I also added a default display style for `ng-include` tag, the browser doesn't know what kind of styles to use, so the tag has no hight and is hard to debug.

I hope I could help you.